# What are the rules for solving differential inequalities using Laplace Transforms?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, laplace-transform

I am looking to solve a non-autonomous differential inequality of the form
$$\frac{dV}{d\tau}-\epsilon V-\frac{E^2}{2\epsilon}\leq\frac{A^2}{2\epsilon}\tau^2+\frac{2AE\tau}{\epsilon},$$where $V:\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$, and $\epsilon$, $E$, and $A$ are positive (non zero) scalar constants.

When I take the Laplace transform, and after some simple algebraic manipulation I obtain
$$(s-\epsilon)\mathcal{V}(s)\leq\frac{A^2}{\epsilon s^3}+\frac{2AE}{\epsilon s^2}+\frac{E^2}{2\epsilon s}+V(0).$$ Now, the question is about how to properly dived both sides by $(s-\epsilon )$ since this, as far as I can tell, is sign indefinite. Now, if I assume that that there is no sign change when I do this operation, followed by partial fraction decomposition and then taking the inverse Laplace transform, I obtain
$$V(\tau)\leq \left(\frac{A^{2}}{\epsilon^{4}}+\frac{E^{2}}{2\epsilon^{2}}+V(0)+\frac{2AE}{\epsilon^{3}}\right)\text{e}^{\epsilon\tau}-\left(\frac{A^{2}}{\epsilon^{3}}+\frac{2AE}{\epsilon^{2}}\right)\tau-\frac{E^{2}}{4\epsilon^{2}}\tau^{2}-\frac{E^{2}}{2\epsilon^{2}}-\frac{A^{2}}{\epsilon^{4}}-\frac{2AE}{\epsilon^{3}}.$$ This seems fine on initial inspection, since $V(\tau)=V(0)$ when $\tau=0$, however, things get odd when you change the value of $\epsilon$. For example, let $A=0.1$, $E=0.2$, $V(0)=0$, then when $\epsilon =0.1$ the value of $V(\tau)<0$ for $\tau\in(1,9)$ (rough bounds). This is a problem since $V$ is a positive definite function (time derivative is positive definite and initial condition here is zero). There is clearly an issue here, and my suspicion is in what I am doing while I am working in the Laplace domain. Now, I see that I can divide equation two by $(s-\epsilon)$ and take it in piecwise form such that
$$\mathcal{V}_{u}(s)\leq\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{s-\epsilon}\left(\frac{A^{2}}{\epsilon}\frac{1}{s^{3}}+\frac{2AE}{\epsilon}\frac{1}{s^{2}}+\frac{E^{2}}{\epsilon2}\frac{1}{s}+V_{u}(t_{0})\right), & s-\epsilon\geq0\\
-\frac{1}{s-\epsilon}\left(\frac{A^{2}}{\epsilon}\frac{1}{s^{3}}+\frac{2AE}{\epsilon}\frac{1}{s^{2}}+\frac{E^{2}}{\epsilon2}\frac{1}{s}+V_{u}(t_{0})\right), & s-\epsilon<0
\end{cases},$$ but how would one take the inverse Laplace transform of this while taking the conditions of the piecewise function into account? Would I do the following
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{s-\epsilon\}$$ and start to look at the time derivatives of the Dirac-delta function? That seems very bizarre to me, so any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. perhaps I shouldn't use Laplace transforms and I should solve this differential inequality by a different method? Suggestions are welcome!

Thanks,
Sage

Comment: Are you aware of Gronwall’s inequality?

Comment: ?? From $\mathcal{L}[f]\le\mathcal{L}[g]$ can we deduce  $f \le g$  ??

Comment: @GEdgar I don't know. I am confused about something, just not sure what.

Comment: @Aruralreader I don't think I can write my differential inequality in the form required for the Gronwall inequality. Gronwall would require $\dot{V}\leq \beta (t) V(t)$, but I have something like $\dot{V}\leq \epsilon V(t)+f(t)$.

Comment: @GEdgar My hunch is, "yes", based on the definition of a Laplace transform. But I don't have a proof in front me.

Comment: $V = V(\tau)$ depends on $\tau \in \mathbb{R}$, doesn't it? Why you wrote $V: \mathbb{R}^{\color{red}{n}} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @NN2 My apologies, that was a typo. It is now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
&\iff \left(\frac{dV}{d\tau}-\epsilon V \right)\leq\frac{A^2}{2\epsilon}\tau^2+\frac{2AE\tau}{\epsilon} + \frac{E^2}{2\epsilon} \\
&\iff \underbrace{\left(\frac{dV}{d\tau}-\epsilon V \right)e^{-\epsilon\tau}}_{=\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(e^{-\epsilon\tau}V  \right)}\leq \left(\frac{A^2}{2\epsilon}\tau^2+\frac{2AE\tau}{\epsilon} + \frac{E^2}{2\epsilon}\right)e^{-\epsilon\tau} \\
&\iff e^{-\epsilon\tau}V(\tau)-V(0) \leq\int_0^\tau  \left(\frac{A^2}{2\epsilon}t^2+\frac{2AE t}{\epsilon} + \frac{E^2}{2\epsilon}\right)e^{-\epsilon t}dt \\
&\iff  V(\tau)\leq V(0) e^{\epsilon\tau}+e^{\epsilon\tau}\int_0^\tau  \left(\frac{A^2}{2\epsilon}t^2+\frac{2AE t}{\epsilon} + \frac{E^2}{2\epsilon}\right)e^{-\epsilon t}dt
\end{align}$$

**Remark**: You can find the analytic expression of the integral easily.

Comment: Ok, so it seems I can solve this using the standard integration factor method. That sounds great (I just need to do the integration). That satisfies my problem on a practical level,  but I'm still left with curiosity about Laplace transforms. Any insights there?

Comment: @SageEdwards Laplace transform is just a (complex) way to find compute the two integrals (in the left and right hand sides of the third line). Normally,you might find the same result if you(could)take the inverse Laplace$$\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{s-\epsilon}\left(\frac{A^{2}}{\epsilon}\frac{1}{s^{3}}+\frac{2AE}{\epsilon}\frac{1}{s^{2}}+\frac{E^{2}}{\epsilon2}\frac{1}{s}+V_{u}(t_{0})\right), & s-\epsilon\geq0\\
-\frac{1}{s-\epsilon}\left(\frac{A^{2}}{\epsilon}\frac{1}{s^{3}}+\frac{2AE}{\epsilon}\frac{1}{s^{2}}+\frac{E^{2}}{\epsilon2}\frac{1}{s}+V_{u}(t_{0})\right), & s-\epsilon<0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I see, after completing the computation I get: $V(t)\leq V(0)\text{e}^{\epsilon t}+\frac{A^{2}}{\epsilon^{4}}\text{e}^{\epsilon t}+\frac{2AE}{\epsilon^{3}}\text{e}^{\epsilon t}+\frac{E^{2}}{2\epsilon^{2}}\text{e}^{\epsilon t}-\frac{A^{2}(\epsilon^{2}t^{2}+2\epsilon t+2)}{2\epsilon^{4}}-\frac{2AE(\epsilon t+1)}{\epsilon^{3}}-\frac{E^{2}}{2\epsilon^{2}}$, which has a similar form, but is subtle enough to make the difference. I now see that I cant use Laplace transforms for differential inequalities, thanks to you and @GEdgar, but I am still left with the question of why.

Comment: @SageEdwards I believe that if $A(t) \ge B(t)$ then $\mathcal{L}(A)(s) \ge \mathcal{L}(B)(s)$. So, it's correct to deduce that $\mathcal{V}(s) \le ....$. However, *I'm not sure* that we can do the same for the inverse Laplace, that means :  if $\mathcal{A}(s) \ge \mathcal{B}(s) \implies \mathcal{L}^{-1}(\mathcal{A})(t) \ge \mathcal{L}^{-1}(\mathcal{B})(t)$

Answer (score 1):

Solving inequalities using Laplace transform ... I do not think that works.

If we find $\mathcal{L}(f) \ge 0$, it does not follow that $f\ge 0$.
Example:
$$
f(t) = \sin t,\qquad \mathcal{L}[f](s) = \frac{1}{1+s^2}
$$
Here $\mathcal{L}[f](s) > 0$ for all $s$, but it is not true that
$f(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to work, but I don't understand why I can't. There is something fundamental that I am missing here...